# Instantiate a SMTPClient without specifying port number

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

In code below, what will be the port number that will be used? There is no mailsettings element in web.config of this Web app.

```
  SMTPClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.abbcd.com);
```

Answer (score 2):

Port numbers depend on the protocol. If you don't specify any, the standard `SMTP` will be used which is port number `25`. This is just to retrieve messages. To post them another one will be used.

Here you can read about those port numbers depending on the protocol and action you want to execute (receive or post): [port numbers for SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).